# Why is object.sort() passing None to variable?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am just learning Python and programming in general and have come across the following question.  I cannot seem to find an answer/explanation to why the statement below passes None in the assignment.  Just trying to understand.  I am oversimplifying below and understand that once I call .sort() on before that before has changed as well.

```
before = [67,45,2,13,1,998]

after = before.sort()

print(after)
```

Why, when I print after is it None?

Comment: Just use before.sort() to print it does not return the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` is an inplace operation, it does not return  a value so as with all python functions that don't return a value returns `None` by default so you are setting `after` to None.

Just call.sort and the print your list:

```
before = [67,45,2,13,1,998]

before.sort() # inplace sorts original list

print(before)
```

Or use sorted if you want a new list:

```
before = [67,45,2,13,1,998]

after = sorted(before) # creates a completely  new list 

print(after)
```